# Why does the backslash behavior change depending on the type of quote

Tags: linux, bash, escaping, echo

I'm very new to bash and came across this example where the output is different depending on the quote type.

Here's the first example:

```
echo -e "\\\\"
```

This prints out one backslash character.
Whereas the following:

```
echo -e '\\\\'
```

Prints two backslash characters.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In double quotes, some characters have special meaning, and a backslash is used to "escape" the special meaning, i.e. insert them literally.

```
"$x"   # Value of the variable $x.
"\$x"  # The string $x.
```

To enter a literal backslash to double quotes, you need to escape it by another backslash, so backslash in double quotes is represented as `\\`.

In single quotes, every character is interpreted literally, so there's no need for an escape character.

Comment: Pedantically: When expressing a literal backslash in a double quoted string, it has to be doubled. `"\\"` is actually a single backslash literal. People wrongly writes `printf "foobar\n"` where to be correct it would have been `printf "foobar\\n"` because the backslash is a literal one in the format string. Bash and ksh and other shell are lenient with this incorrect unescaped backslash in double quotes. Though, this is why I always prefer to use single quotes in shell string literals, unless I need to use single quotes in it. `printf 'foobar\n'` is correct because of single quote.

Comment: @LéaGris: True, I updated the wording a bit. What other options were there for shell creators to handle a backslash before a non-special character? The backslash can disappear (that's what happens in Perl, with a warning) or maybe an error is thrown? It's too late to change the behaviour now :-)